# MUI - How to position Select options above the Select Component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to position the options ***(the number of options are dynamic)*** of an MUI(v5) Select Component above it. My initial code goes something like this:

```
<Select ... >
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 3</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Which would be rendered similar to this:
[image]

I was thinking that changing the anchorOrigin of the MenuProps so that the options would be positioned above the Select Component instead:

```
<Select 
  ...
  MenuProps={{
    anchorOrigin: {
      vertical: 'top',
      horizontal: 'center',
  }}
>
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem ... >Menu 3</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Which was rendered similar to this:

[image]

Which wasn't what I wanted. This is would be similar to what I'd want it to look like:

[image]

I thought I could use the `MenuProps -> PaperProps -> style -> transform` property to place it above but since the options are dynamic I can't really do that.

Any suggestions or reading materials you could refer to me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the space you have on top. If there is enough space then the dropdown will populate on top. But in this case input is positioned closely to top so there isn't enough space left to open the dropdown on top

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka you mean on the screen? This Input is placed near the bottom so there should be enough space but it's still behaving the way I described it.

Comment: did you find the solution for this? I'm having the exact same issue and I haven't been able to make it work